# Haskell case statement

Tags: haskell, input, case, switch-statement

I have code something like this

```
main :: [[String]] -> IO ()
main st = do
    answer <- getLine
    case answer of
      "q" -> return ()
      "load" x -> main $ parseCSV $ readFile x
```

This doesn't work, so my question is how can I use case switch statement for something of  changing input
For example in my code I want the input from a user to be either q or a load, but the load will constant change:

```
load "sample.csv"
load "test.csv"
load "helloworld.csv"
```

In my code I indicated the constantly changing input as X, but this doesn't work as I expected it.

Help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: can you add compiler error to your question?

Comment: @KrzysztoChrobak: The error is quite obvious — `"load" x` is not a valid pattern.

Comment: You should check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602243/pattern-matching-string-prefixes-in-haskell

Comment: Oops, forgot to add: the question is about pattern-matching a prefix of a string, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis that was actually helpfull, but Im not sure how to relate it to my problem, I cant do something like stripPrefix since I am going to expand the case switch for multiple entries, and stripPrefix would only work for 1, the ('l':'o':'a':'d': x) -> seems to error saying it doesnt allow something like ->, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the problem is with your pattern matching.

Here's a simple way to get around this (and still have something readable).

1. Split `answer` into words for matching (with the `words` function).
2. Use the first word in the pattern match.
3. If you want to use the remaining "words", simply `unwords` the remaining elems in the list to get a string.

Example:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    answer <- getLine
    case words answer of
        ("q":_)    -> putStrLn "I'm quitting!"
        ("load":x) -> putStrLn ("Now I will load " ++ unwords x)
        otherwise  -> putStrLn "Not sure what you want me to do!"
```

Note - the `x` you had above is actually `unwords x` here.

Comment: If the code I've pasted here works for you (exactly as-is), and is generally what you want to do, but you are having trouble with a compile error you cannot get past, that would be a good topic for another question.

Comment: thank you :) sorry for the hassle, it was my coding fault. I was just wondering because the error occurred on the brackets of the ("q":_), thank you again