# How to "stripPrefix" where the prefix can be one of multiple strings

Tags: string, list, haskell

I was trying to write a function that takes a list of strings and a string and for each element in the list removes it from the seceond string if it is a prefix of the second string. Let me illustrate this with some code.

This is what i've got:

```
myFunc string =
    if restIsJust
        then restOfString
        where
        (restIsJust, restOfString) =
            case stripPrefix "string1" string of
                Just something  -> case stripPrefix "string2" something of
                    Just somethingelse  -> (True, somethingelse)
                    Nothing             -> (True, something)
                Nothing         -> (False, undefined)
```

Currently it strips `string1` and then `string2` consecutively.

I'd much rather be able to say sth. like

```
myFunc string =
    if restIsJust
        then restOfString
        where
        (restIsJust, restOfString) =
            case myStripPrefix ["string1" "string2"] string of
                Just something  -> (True, somethingelse)
                Nothing         -> (False, undefined)
```

mostly because it doesn't look as ugly but also because I might want to extend the list of strings at some point.

How can I define `myStripPrefix`?

I'm also open to any other solution that provides the desired functionality.

I've grabbed the original code snippet from
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1602296/14700631
and modified it to have this second `case`statement. This already took me a good while tearing my hair out. I do, by now, understand what the above code does but Haskell overall is still mostly greek to me. So I'm really open for suggestions.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried defining it yourself? Did you get stuck on something?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to just write a parser? Haskell has some of the best libraries around for prototyping in that domain.

Comment: @Noughtmare to be honest I did not. See my edited post above. I tried to provide some more detail as to what my issue is. That's basically as far as I got...

Comment: @DanielWagner I'm really open to suggestions. Kindly have a look at my edited post above. It's more like I'm only dipping my toes with Haskell at this point... and I was already happy to have gotten this to do what I wanted :D

Comment: Do you know how to write a recursive function that iterates over a list? If so, please try writing your `myStripPrefix` and show the code in your question. If not, I'd suggest taking a step back and reviewing learning materials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your first, two-prefix example, it appears to me that you want to remove a list of prefixes, *in order*, only continuing to the next prefix if the previous prefix was successfully removed.  In other words, you want something like:

```
λ> stripPrefixes ["a","b","c"] "abd"
"d"       -- removes, "a", then "b", but can't remove "c"
λ> stripPrefixes ["a","b","c"] "bcd"
"bcd"     -- can't remove "a", so stops immediately w/o trying others
```

This is a good example of use of recursion and case matching, and these are key concepts that you'll want to practice when learning Haskell.  If I were writing this function, I'd start by writing the type signature.  You can waste a lot of time chasing down pointless, confusing errors, if you don't make it clear to Haskell exactly what sort of function you're trying to write, so always start with that:

```
stripPrefixes :: [String] -> String -> String
```

Because the first argument to `stripPrefixes` is a list of prefixes, I know that I'm going to need to handle two cases -- the case where this list of prefixes is non-empty, and the case where it's empty, so I next write:

```
stripPrefixes (pfx:pfxs) str = _
stripPrefixes [] str = _
```

The second case is easy.  If there are no prefixes to remove, we return the string as-is:

```
stripPrefixes [] str = str
```

For the first case, I want to try to remove the first prefix, using the `stripPrefix` library funcion:

```
... stripPrefix pfx str ...
```

Because this returns a `Maybe String`, I need to handle `Just` and `Nothing` values.  But, I don't need to calculate boolean flags or do anything else complicated.  I can *and should* directly case match on the result of this expression:

```
stripPrefixes (pfx:pfxs) str = case stripPrefix pfx str of
  Nothing -> _
  Just rest -> _
```

To be clear, this is what I've written so far:

```
import Data.List

stripPrefixes :: [String] -> String -> String
stripPrefixes (pfx:pfxs) str = case stripPrefix pfx str of
  Nothing -> _
  Just rest -> _
stripPrefixes [] str = str
```

Now, the `Nothing` case is pretty easy.  If I'm trying to remove a list of prefixes, and the first prefix can't be removed, according to the specifications for my function, I'm done, and I can return the string as-is:

```
  Nothing -> str
```

For the `Just` case, this indicates that I've successfully removed the first prefix `pfx` and now must remove the rest of the `pfxs` from the rest of the string.  I can do this recursively:

```
  Just rest -> stripPrefixes pfxs rest
                             ^^^^ ^^^^
                                |    |
                                |    ` rest of string
                                `-- rest of prefixes
```

giving me the final solution:

```
import Data.List

stripPrefixes :: [String] -> String -> String
stripPrefixes (pfx:pfxs) str = case stripPrefix pfx str of
  Nothing -> str
  Just rest -> stripPrefixes pfxs rest
stripPrefixes [] str = str
```

For practice, I would suggest you try writing two more versions:

1. `stripFirstPrefix` -- Remove only the *first* matching prefix, returning the string as-is if none of the prefixes can be removed.
2. `stripAllPrefixes` -- Try removing *each* of the prefixes, in order, continuing through the complete list even if some of the prefixes can't be removed.  (e.g., `stripAllPrefixes ["a","b","c"] "ace"` successfully removes `"a"`, fails to remove `"b"`, but then successfully removes `"c"`, leaving `"e"`).

You should be able to write both these functions with the same template *only* filling in different expressions in place of the underscores, but try writing them from scratch first, just like I described above, and copy these templates only if you get stuck:

```
stripFirstPrefix :: [String] -> String -> String
stripFirstPrefix (pfx:pfxs) str = case stripPrefix pfx str of
  Nothing -> _
  Just rest -> _
stripFirstPrefix [] str = str

stripAllPrefixes :: [String] -> String -> String
stripAllPrefixes (pfx:pfxs) str = case stripPrefix pfx str of
  Nothing -> _
  Just rest -> _
stripAllPrefixes [] str = str
```

**SPOILERS**

.

.

.

If you need more hints:

- For `stripFirstPrefix`, the recursive call will occur in the `Nothing` case because we only need to continue to other prefixes if the first prefix `pfx` *can't* be removed.
- For `stripAllPrefixes`, recursive calls will occur in both the `Nothing` and `Just` calls, because we keep trying to strip prefixes, whether the first `stripPrefix` succeeds (`Just ...`) or fails (`Nothing`).

**COMPLETE SPOILERS**

.

.

.

Here are the answers:

```
stripFirstPrefix :: [String] -> String -> String
stripFirstPrefix (pfx:pfxs) str = case stripPrefix pfx str of
  Nothing -> stripFirstPrefix pfxs str
  Just rest -> rest
stripFirstPrefix [] str = str

stripAllPrefixes :: [String] -> String -> String
stripAllPrefixes (pfx:pfxs) str = case stripPrefix pfx str of
  Nothing -> stripAllPrefixes pfxs str
  Just rest -> stripAllPrefixes pfxs rest
stripAllPrefixes [] str = str
```

and here's a refactored version of `stripAllPrefixes` that takes advantage of the fact that in both cases of the `case` statement, the recursive call is nearly the same:

```
stripAllPrefixes :: [String] -> String -> String
stripAllPrefixes (pfx:pfxs) str
  = stripAllPrefixes pfxs $ case stripPrefix pfx str of
                              Nothing -> str
                              Just rest -> rest
stripAllPrefixes [] str = str
```

Comment: thanks so much for describing your thought process behind this. Actually what I was after was the 2nd practice case you left me, though I think I will now be able to write that one given the "base case" and your reasoning behind it! :)